# AWS lambda function & S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda function in Node.js 6.10 on AWS that gets triggered when an object is uploaded into S3 and I have no idea where to even begin. Can someone please help?

Comment: Follow the tutorial: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

Answer (score 3):

Below is the post from AWS guys on the same scenario.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html

The idea is simple, You need to configure events on the S3 bucket to invoke your lambda. These events for your case should be put and multi-part complete.

Below is the screenshot of event configuration

[image]

You can find events under properties tab of the S3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

Use SAM (Serverless Application Model). Here's some info:
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#s3

Here's where you can find an actual example of the code and the SAM template:
https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/tree/develop/examples/apps/s3-get-object